# Find the possible values of $n$?

Tags: arithmetic

The equation is $$n=\frac{\sqrt{16m^{2}+x^2}-x}{m}$$ $x>0$,$m>0$ and $n$ is a positive integer.How many values of $n$ are possible?

Comment: Hint: $n <4$ so $1,2,3$ are the only possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) let  $4m=2pqk, x=k(p^2-q^2)$

$$n=4\cdot\dfrac{(p^2+q^2)-(p^2-q^2)}{2pq}=\cdots=\dfrac{4q}p$$

So,  all we need is $p|4q$

Comment: It is a helpful post but would you please tell me how you got the intuition about m.Thanks

Comment: @Unique, We need $$(4m)^2+x^2$$ to be perfect square, right?

Comment: yeah,I understood it.